# Is this subset of $[0,1]$ of second category?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $S$ be an uncountable subset of $[0,1]$ such that:

1. $S$ is dense in $[0,1]$;
2. as a topological space, $S$ is [Baire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space).

> Is it true that $S$ is of second category as a subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Every relatively open set has the form $U\cap S$, where $U$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

> **Lemma.** Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $S$ is dense in $X$.  If $U$ is open and dense in $X$, then $U \cap S$ is open and dense in the relative topology on $S$.

*Proof*.  $U \cap S$ is open in $S$ (i.e. is an open set in the relative topology of $S$) by definition of the relative topology.  Suppose $V \subset S$ is open in $S$ and nonempty.  Then $V$ is of the form $V = W \cap S$ for some (nonempty) open $W \subset X$.  Now since $U$ is open and dense, $W \cap U$ is a nonempty open set in $X$, so it intersects the dense set $S$.  Thus $S \cap (W \cap U) = V \cap (U \cap S)$ is nonempty.  Since $V$ was arbitrary, $U \cap S$ is dense in $S$.

Now to your question.  Let $U_n$ be any sequence of dense open sets in $X = [0,1]$.  Then each $U_n \cap S$ is dense and open in $S$.  Since $S$ is Baire, we have $S \cap \bigcap_n U_n = \bigcap_n (U_n \cap S) \ne \emptyset$.  So $S$ intersects every countable intersection of dense open sets, and is therefore second category in $X$.

Comment: Thanks, I delete the comments that are not relevant anymore.